# Declaring 2 (or even multi-) dimensional std::arrays elegantly

Tags: c++, stdarray

I'm using 2-dimensional arrays based on `std::array`.

Basically instead of:

```
MyType myarray[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE];
```

I have:

```
std::array<std::array<MyType, Y_SIZE>, X_SIZE> myarray;
```

This works perfectly fine but IMO the declaration is not very readable.

Is there a way to declare this using some clever C++ template mecanism, so the declaration could look something like this?

```
My2DArray<Mytype, X_SIZE, Y_SIZE> myarray;
```

Comment: I don't think code elegance was/is a priority of 'Modern' C++!

Comment: I would expect it to be `[Y][X]` (and `std::array<std::array<T, X>, Y>` in the template in the answer), as usually I think about X being the base dimension, which is iterated mostly continuously.. (of course if you iterate mostly through Y, then your example is optimal too, so it depends on the usage)

Comment: @Ped7g no, X,Y rather than Y,X is on purpose because accessing is done like this: `myarray[x_index][y_index]`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky that's what I am talking about, if it's for example `int map[4][3];` then the memory layout is `[0][0], [0][1], [0][2], [1][0], [1][1], ...`, i.e. the second dimension form continuous blocks of integers, so you should (when possible) iterate over second dimension in the inner loop, and first dimension in the outer loop. In your dimension that means to have X as outer loop and Y inner (I mean for cases where this distinction is even possible, like adding of matrices, in multiplying it doesn't matter that much, as one of the two matrices has to be traversed in suboptimal order), etc

Comment: @Ped7g it's not about optimisation here but solely about code readability. But you are right.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want just 2D arrays, it's fairly straightforward:

```
template <class T, std::size_t X, std::size_t Y>
using My2DArray = std::array<std::array<T, Y>, X>;
```

If you want a generic mechanism not limited to 2D arrays, it can be done too:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... Ns>
struct AddArray {
    using type = std::array<typename AddArray<T, Ns...>::type, N>;
};

template <class T, std::size_t N>
struct AddArray<T, N> {
    using type = std::array<T, N>;
};

template <class T, std::size_t... N>
using MyNDArray = typename AddArray<T, N...>::type;
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c902bc2af3637f8)

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat elegant way to implement this operation is with a fold expression:

```cpp
// Some namespace to hide the poorly-constrained template function:
namespace array_making {
    template <std::size_t N>
    struct array_dim {};

    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    constexpr auto operator%(array_dim<N>, T const&)
        -> std::array<T, N>;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
using md_array_t = decltype(
    (array_making::array_dim<Is>{} % ... % std::declval<T>())
);
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/uz5Mbb).

Then `md_array_t<int, 1, 2, 3>` is `array<array<array<int, 3>, 2>, 1>`. If you prefer the opposite order, reverse the parameters of the `operator%` and the arguments to the fold expression.

---

Note that this will run into problems if the type `T` has an unconstrained `operator%` in an associated namespace (please constrain your operators!). We can reduce the risk of this happening by choosing unlikely operators such as `.*`, `->*`, or `%=`; or we can use an `array_type<T>` wrapper. Neither solution completely avoids the problem of improperly constrained operator overloads for `T`.

Answer (score 3):

We can wrap one of the existing [`MyNDArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57758674/1896169) / [`md_array_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57764681/1896169) answers to arrive at an alternative interface:

```cpp
template <typename Arr, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto make_array_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> md_array_t<std::remove_all_extents_t<Arr>,
        std::extent_v<Arr, Is>...>;

template <typename Arr>
using make_array = decltype(make_array_impl<Arr>(
    std::make_index_sequence<std::rank_v<Arr>>{}));
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/809IRP)

This allows us to write `make_array<int[4][5][6]>` to mean `array<array<array<int, 6>, 5, 4>`.

---

Explanation:

1. [`std:rank`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) gives the number of dimensions of an array type. Thus, for `int[4][5][6]`, it returns 3.
2. We hand this to [`make_index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to end up with a pack of indices. (`0, 1, 2`)
3. [`std::remove_all_extents`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_all_extents) gives us the underlying type of the array; `T[a][b]...[n]` -> `T` (`int`)
4. [`std::extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent) gives us the extent of the given dimension. We call this for each index. (`4, 5, 6`).

By passing these to our previously-implemented `md_array_t`, we end up with `md_array_t<int, 4, 5, 6>`, which produces what we want.